# Getting two messages from receive when only one is sent

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I wrote a server that should wait for messages from a client after opening a connection to it:

```
while(1){
  if(recv(mySocket, buffer, 1000, 0) < 1){
     continue;
  }   
  printf("Message received: %s", buffer);
}
```

I checked with wireshark which packets were sent to this server, but for every packet sent there were 2 printf outputs.

My question is now where did I get this additional message from.

(The additional message are some random bytes. But every time the same.)

Comment: Have you received two packets?

Comment: @Ed Heal Well printf is called two times -> so recv also returns 2 times, but the client only sends one packet

Comment: Save the return value from recv in a variable and print it each time. If it's zero then you did *not* receive a message so should not print buffer.

Comment: @jarmod I changed if(recv(mySocket, buffer, 1000, 0) == -1) to if(recv(mySocket, buffer, 1000, 0) < 1) but nothing has changed.

Comment: what kind of socket is this? and what's the packet length?

Comment: @Karoly Horvath It's a TCP socket and the contentlength is always 1000 bytes

Comment: Does wireshark show 1000 byte packets?

Comment: Additionally, in TCP there's no such thing as a "message". Only a sequence of bytes.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, you are correct that TCP has no concept of "message", but POSIX `send()` and `recv()` do, regardless of the type of the underlying socket.

Comment: Can you present the code by which messages are *sent*?  Alternatively, do you have any specification for how messages are sent or for their form or content?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I just wanted to warn the OP not to structure his code based on the idea that he will receive "messages". And the fact that he's using those API calls doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Do you see "Message received:" twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your apparent expectations for the behavior of `recv()` are not justified.  As @KarolyHorvath observed in comments, stream sockets (among which TCP-based sockets fall) have no sense whatever of "messages".  In particular, network packets do not correspond to messages on a stream socket.  POSIX has this to say about the behavior of `recv()`, in fact:

> For stream-based sockets, [...] message boundaries shall be ignored.

Although that's more likely to have the effect of combining multiple "messages", it *can* also mean that a single message (as dispatched by a single `send()` call) is split over multiple `recv()` calls.  It certainly **will** mean that if the buffer length you specify to `recv()` is less than the number of bytes actually received on the socket, but there are other circumstances in which that result could be obtained, too.

On success, `recv()` returns the number of bytes copied into the receive buffer.  If you are genuinely trying to implement some sort of "message" exchange, then you can use that to help you split incoming data on message boundaries.  Do recognize, however, that that constitutes implementing a message-passing protocol on top of a stream, so sender and receiver need to cooperate, at least implicitly, for it to work.

Comment: I think there's more to this, and your answer is almost certainly incomplete, but I'm waiting for the OP to respond...

Comment: You are right. the packet was split because the size of the receive buffer was a few bytes to small.

Comment: @scaletos, I'm glad you've identified the issue.  I reiterate, however, that the number of packets coming across a TCP connection, and the sizes of their payloads, are largely incidental to `recv()`.  You may find that receiving into a sufficiently large buffer *often* allows you to read packet by packet, but you cannot rely on "messages" sent via `send()` to correspond 1:1 with packets, or with packets received on such a connection to correspond 1:1 with "messages" received by `recv()`.

Answer (score 0):

John Bollinger's answer is accurate and provides insight into what you should do to create a reliable client / server application.

Regarding your question, There is another problem that explains the actual output you see. the packet is most probably sent and received in a single chunk, as you observe with wireshark. The bug is in your server:  You receive the data in a char array and print it directly as a string with `printf`. I suspect the packet does not contain the terminating `'\0'` to make the buffer a proper string for `"%s"`. `printf` will output the packet contents plus whatever buffer contents is there until it reaches a `'\0'` byte, possibly invoking undefined behaviour. If the packet is split in several chunks, you may see the same contents several times, and random characters too.

Here is how you should fix your code:

```
char buffer[2000];
...
for (;;) {
    ssize_t count = recv(mySocket, buffer, 1999, 0);

    if (count >= 1) {
        buffer[count] = '\0';
        printf("Message received: |%s|", buffer);
    }
}
```

Note that the buffer must be at least 1 byte longer than the maximum packet size, and this tracing method cannot handle embedded `'\0'` bytes in the packets.

Of course the packets can be sliced and diced on the way between the client and the server, so you must deal with this appropriately to implement a proper protocol.

Comment: Thanks but my server was only meant to print messages smaller than 1000 bytes including the nullbyte.

Comment: @scaleos: do you transmit the `'\0'` byte as part of the packet?